# Dart2JS and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, dart

So I'm researching new frameworks and am really impressed with what I've read about Dart. Of course, I have to support at least IE8, and Dart doesn't seem to provide that. I was wondering why exactly that is. Is it just because it compiles to ES5? Would some simple polyfills fix that?

Comment: Microsoft support and patches for XP and IE8 end soon - this year I think.

Comment: If only :(  IE8 shipped with Windows 7, so my understanding is they share the same lifecycle.  Which means Primary Support ends in 2015 and Extended Support ends in 2020.

Comment: Yikes - long live Intranet Explorer. At least this will only be on corporate networks. I wonder what the web stats are for the IE8/Windows 7 combination. Must be vanishingly small. I couldn't find any combined os/browser stats. This doesn't help your situation though. I guess one approach would be running the dart2js output (non-minified) through a linter and see what kind of problems it identifies.

Comment: Don't forget IE7 on Server 2008 R1 which also ends support on 2020 thanks to R1/R2 having the same lifecycle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Thank's for checking out Dart, we're glad you like what you see!)

Dart is from the future, today. Look at any trends, and one thing is clear: mobile, mobile, mobile. Oh, and also modern browsers that auto-update.

Spending any time working on legacy browsers, with their outdated JavaScript engines and feeble support for HTML5 (if any), means we're *not* spending time working on a comprehensive platform for developers to build apps that wow users. We believe that user expectations are high, and the only way to meet and exceed them is to build a platform that runs on modern JavaScript engines and can exploit the wide array of HTML5 features. You just can't build a fantastic experience that shows off the power of the modern web *and* support legacy browsers.

For a quick fix, encourage your users who are stuck on legacy browsers to install Chrome Frame. Or, better yet, encourage them to upgrade their browsers.

As to *what* prevents Dart from being used in legacy browsers:

- Lack of testing. Our [buildbots](http://buildbot.dartlang.org) don't test against legacy browsers.
- Lack of ES5 JavaScript engines.
- Manpower. Our resources are better used building for modern web browsers.

I'm not sure if we explored if an ES5 shim would work. We'd love to hear from the community if they get this to work, though.

Comment: Hi Seth, thanks for your response. I probably should have rephrased the question. I get *why* Dart doesn't support IE8 (believe me, you're preaching to the choir ;) but I don't quite understand *what* prevents it. Is it just because it compiles to ES5? If that's the case, an ES5 shim would allow me to move to Dart while still supporting that segment of my userbase.  Unfortunately, I can't really require Chrome Frame out of my paying customers.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I added a bit to the answer. Not sure if it's what you're looking for. :( BTW Chrome Frame no longer requires admin privs to install, which is nice.

Comment: According to StatCounter, IE8 is at around 10% http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201203-201303

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of which browsers support dart2js? Is it happy on all the mobile browsers?

Comment: @pseudopeach dart2js targets modern and mobile browsers. IE9+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera. Also, Chrome for Android, Mobile Safari.

Comment: @SethLadd, thanks. I'm really excited about Dart. You guys are doing a great job!

Comment: Chrome Frame is no longer an option as of January 2014.  Google is shutting it down: http://blog.chromium.org/2013/06/retiring-chrome-frame.html